# Subclassing PFObject And Overriding Dynamically Added Accessors

Tags: dynamic, parse-platform, overriding, accessor, subclassing

I understand how to subclass PFObject, but I am not certain how to perform additional custom code in an accessor, while still calling the generic implementation of that accessor as defined and @dynamic-ally added by Parse (which does the proper thing depending on the property's type, e.g. PFRelation, and so forth).

For instance...

```
// MyPFObjectSubclass.h
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
@interface MyPFObjectSubclass.h : PFObject<PFSubclassing>
@property (retain, nonatomic) id myProperty;
+ (NSString *)parseClassName;
@end

// MyPFObjectSubclass.m
#import "MyPFObjectSubclass.h"
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>
@implementation MyPFObjectSubclass
@dynamic myProperty;
+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return @"MyPFObjectSubclass";
}
- (void)setMyProperty:(id)someProperty {
    // insert some custom code here, e.g. for validation...
    // call the generic, dynamic implementation of setMyProperty, but how?
    // obviously, you cannot call [super setMyProperty:someProperty];
}
@end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you doing on this? Did you get any further?

Comment: I think the ultimate method that gets called when we set a value for  dynamic properties we have specified for PFObject subclasses is -[PFObject setObject:forKey:], the key being the name of your property. so should prob'ly call that at the end of your custom code

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is implement your own accessors and skip @dynamic